# CSS3 box shadows and Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, css

I am developing a site using Bootstrap 3 and everything seems to work except when i try to use CSS3 box shadows.

What I want to achieve is have box shadows on the left and right of the whole content div.  this works fine.  i also want a box shadow on some of the content items such as divs in the sidebar but if I have box shadows on the main content container, it doesn't work for the others.  If I remove the box shadow class on the main content container, the rest all work.

If i remove this div `<div class="box outer">`, all the other box shadows work but if this is in, then they don't show.

Any help on identifying why I can't use both box shadows at once would be appreciated

**UPDATE:**
Got a demo on Bootply http://www.bootply.com/ULX2kATkT8 of what it looks like, I just added a width to `.outer` given it a width of 1000px and I can see that both all shadows are visible but it looks like the `.outer` shadow overwrites the others

Here is my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Set the viewport so this responsive site displays correctly on mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 3 Responsive Design</title>
    <!-- Include bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="http://localhost/app/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/app/public/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/media.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box outer">
        <!-- Site header and navigation -->
        <header class="top" role="header">
            <div class="container">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="logo.png">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        </ul>
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Site banner -->
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="box contentimg">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://localhost/app/public/images/layout/index.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Middle content section -->
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Main Content section -->
                <div class="col-md-8 content">

                </div>
                <!-- End Main Content section -->
                <!-- Sidebar Content section -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="box sidebar_item">
                        <div class="sidebar_item_head"><h3>Events Planner</h3></div>
                        <div class="sidebar_item_main">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Site footer -->
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Content for the first footer section.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Content for the second footer section.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Content for the third footer section.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Include jQuery and bootstrap JS plugins -->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://localhost/app/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/app/public/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

followed by my css

```
    .box {
    position:relative;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    margin:0 10px;
}

.box:before, .box:after {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    content:"";
}

.outer {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.contentimg {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar_item {
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 310px;
}

.outer:before,
.outer:after {
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius:2%/100%;
    -moz-border-radius:2%/100%;
    -webkit-border-radius:2%/100%;
    box-shadow:-10px 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow:-10px 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow:-10px 0 7px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}
.outer:before{
    box-shadow:10px 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow:10px 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow:10px 0 7px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}

.sidebar_item:before,
.sidebar_item:after,
.contentimg:before,
.contentimg:after {
    bottom:12px;
    left:5px;
    width:50%;
    top:80%;
    max-width:300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 7px rgba(0,0,0, 0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow:0 15px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    transform:rotate(-3deg);
}
.sidebar_item:after,
.contentimg:after {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(3deg);
    transform:rotate(3deg);
    right:5px;
    left:auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you set up a demo on http://www.bootply.com/ ?

Comment: @3rror404, I've just added link to Bootply

Comment: The z-index of -1 on it is causing it to not display at all. It is probably safe to say you need that box in the parent and the pseudos nested a bit further down rather than on the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew z-index had something to do with it as I could see the box shadow if i gave the .outer div a width.

I fixed it by adding this to my css

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2,
 .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, 
.col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6,
 .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8,
 .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10,
 .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, 
.col-lg-12 {
    z-index: 0; 
}
```